# Pod Install operation time out github

Tags: github, cocoapods

I tried to install using `pod install` but I experienced an error like in the picture below.

This happen after update the mac os to ventura

Can anyone help me? I cannot install any library.

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (5.8.0)

[!] Error installing Alamofire
[!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git /var/folders/0r/gfzkt7vn7l52g7qr143xl35r0000gn/T/d20230915-7029-zbb6cl --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 5.8.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/0r/gfzkt7vn7l52g7qr143xl35r0000gn/T/d20230915-7029-zbb6cl'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 20.205.243.166]: errno=Operation timed out

Comment: Loading Alamofire with (less tedious) Swift Package Manager is not an option?

Comment: In Swift Package Manager also cannot